# Area of a parallelogram with three dimensional vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

There is a parallelogram that has the vertices **0**, **a**, **b**, and **a+b**, all of which are three dimensional vectors.

**a** =  \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -6 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}**b** = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}

I know that the formula for two dimensional vectors is:

If **u**= $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$ and **v** =$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$, the parallelogram that has the vertices **0**, **a**, **b**, and **a+b** has area $|ay-bx|$. What would the formula look like for three dimensional vectors?

Comment: Have a look at Prof. Josiah Willard Gibbs' geometric definition of the cross (or skew) product, and realize that $A\sin \theta$ is just the height of a parallelogram.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420006/why-does-cross-product-give-a-vector-which-is-perpendicular-to-a-plane

Answer (score 1):

Form a matrix $A$ whose columns are the given vectors.  Then $\det (A^TA)$ is the square of the area of the parallelogram.  This generalizes easily to $k$ vectors in ${\Bbb R}^n$.

Comment: Do you have any references for this one? This is awesome!!

Comment: Look at the section on the Gram determinant here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate that :)

Answer (score 1):

A parallelogram with side lengths $a$ and $b$, with angle $\theta$ between them always has area

$$ab\sin\theta,$$

regardless of the dimension in which the parallelogram lives. Here, $a = \lVert {\bf a} \rVert$, $b$ is defined analogously, and you can find $\theta$ using the standard technique involving the dot product.

As you're seeing, there are many equivalent formulas for the area.

Answer (score 0):

Take the cross product. Or, more generally for vectors in $\Bbb R^n$, take the wedge product.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra