# Please explain (visually would be appreciated) how $u{\times}v$ is orthogonal to both $u$ and $v$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, self-learning

> $u{\times}v$ is orthogonal to both $u$ and $v$.

I tried to visualise the above, but couldn't do it. If $u{\times}v$ is orthogonal to both $u$ and $v$, then provided that the angle between $u$ and $v$ $\theta \neq 0$, then the triangle formed between $u$, $v$ and $u{\times}v$ would have a total internal angle value greater than $180^o$.

Comment: Isn't the vector $u \times v$ perpendicular to the plane that contains $u$ and $v?$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#/media/File:Cross_product_vector.svg

Comment: There is no "triangle formed between $\vec u,\vec v$ and $\vec u\times \vec  v$".  These vectors do not lie in a single plane.

Comment: This is related  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420006/why-does-cross-product-give-a-vector-which-is-perpendicular-to-a-plane

Comment: What's your *definition* of $u\times v$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold you finger's like this:

[image]

Suppose you want to do $B \times I$. The angle between $B$ and $I$ does not have to be 90. It is that the vector that the cross product produces, is $90$ **to the plane that B and I span**. Notice that $F$ and $B$ are $90$ degrees apart, and same for $F$ and $I$.

Now consider this:

[image]

These are three dimensional planes, that you two vectors that you are crossing span. When you cross the two vectors, it produces a vector in another plane that is perpendicular ($90$ degrees) to the other two. The other two need not be perpendicular too. It's just that the **result** that you get is.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. It was not "how" so much as "why"

Comment: I mistakenly downvoted (I was trying to accept your answer) please edit so I can accept and upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: if $u$ is a vector on the ground, pointing North, and $v$ is a vector on the ground, pointing in some other direction, say southwest, from the same point, then $u\times v$ would be a vector pointing straight up to the zenith of the sky. Thus, it is perpendicular to both $u$ and $v$.

Does that visualization help?

Comment: Thanks, that the vector was in a different plane and what I was missing.