# How do taking vector product of two vectors gives us another vector which is PERPENDICULAR TO BOTH THE VECTORS?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I know that to get a vector perpendicular to another two vectors, we need to take the cross product of that two vectors. But I don't know why it is like that.

Anybody pls explain why it is so intuitively or just give me the proof or something.........,

Thank you!

Comment: It is simply [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Definition).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420006/why-does-cross-product-give-a-vector-which-is-perpendicular-to-a-plane

Comment: Two vectors in general define a plane: the plane containing the two lines corresponding to the vectors. The cross product is **defined** to identify the vector perpendicular to the plane containing them, that again identifies the plane univocally.

Comment: Guys thank u for all of u! I got my doubt cleared.
Thank u  so much all.