Why are the projections of an area element onto the coordinate planes the components of its normal vector?
I understand that the components of the cross product $\bf{u}\times\bf{v}$ are the area of the parallelogram enclosed by $\bf{u}$ and $\bf{v}$, projected onto the respective coordinate planes (e.g. the z-component of the cross product is the parallelogram area projected onto the xy-plane, etc.).
Is there a geometric reasoning why the vector resulting from these components is actually normal to the area element? Of course this can easily be shown algebraically by taking dot products of $\bf{u}\times\bf{v}$ with $\bf{u}$ and $\bf{v}$ which are zero, but if possible I'd like some kind of intuitive explanation that is not based on equations.

Can we assume it is already understood that the magnitude of $u\times v$ is equal to the area of the parallelogram? And that $u\times v$ is perpendicular to the parallelogram?

@DavidK To my understanding, #2 is exactly what I am asking, so no, please do not assume :). #1 is a good question, didn't really think about it but honestly I don't think I'm convinced of that too much either.

OK. Sometimes (usually?) the cross product is introduced as the vector with these two properties, and then a formula for computing the components is presented. If the question is answered as you intended to ask it, the answer could be used to show that the formula actually does produce a vector with those two properties.

@DavidK Yes, I think that's right on point. I can see on my own that the algebraic equations for the cross product components are equal to the geometrically projected areas, but I can't see why if we assemble a vector from these three numbers, it has to be normal to the parallelogram and has the parallelogram area as magnitude.

I'd refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420006/why-does-cross-product-give-a-vector-which-is-perpendicular-to-a-plane . This question is pretty much a duplicate.

@IanOgden Whether or not the question is a duplicate I guess I will leave for votes to decide. Anyway I read all the answers there, and none provide the insight I am looking for.

@MaxD Fair enough. I think the bottom line is that the cross product is defined to be perpendicular. It so happens that the method of computing the cross product (i.e. the determinant of the matrix) places the resulting vector in such a dimension. I'd argue that it makes sense to be perpendicular, since its relative direction shouldn't be any different for u over v and vice versa. Unfortunately, I'm not sure a clever intuition exists for why this has to be the case.

@MaxD Am I right in thinking that the difference between this and the suggested duplicate is that you could rephrase your question entirely without the cross product? Eg "let $OPQR$ be a parallelogram in 3D. If the areas of the projections of $OPQR$ onto the planes $x=0$, $y=0$ and $z=0$ are $A_x$, $A_y$ and $A_z$ respectively, then prove that the vector $\left(A_x,A_y,A_z\right)^T$ is perpendicular to the plane containing $OPQR$." Where I'm getting a little confused is how to incorporate signed areas here.

@ChrisLewis Yes, exactly. I believe it is even valid for any flat shape, so the parallelogram part could probably be left out. I'm not overly concerned about the signs, I imagine once I understand the geometry this will fall into place by itself, by giving areas an "up" and "down" side.

This question has been closed since my last comment, in which I pointed out how it differs from a proposed duplicate. Would someone who voted to close please explain what OP might need to do to get it reopened?

This follows up on the idea floated by Chris Lewis.
It uses physical intuition to explain the plausibility of the cross-product formula for the area-normal vector.
Given a right-angled set of coordinate axes, place a point on each axis and at the origin, and from these vertices make a tetrahedron that has three triangular faces on coordinate planes and one slanted transparent triangular face $S$ . Pick any unit vector $\vec n$  and imagine a uniformly intense beam of sunlight consisting of parallel rays travelling in the direction of $\vec n$.

The flux of solar energy entering through face $S$ is equal to the foreshortened area that $S$ presents when viewed by an observer looking in the direction $\vec n$. It also equals the sum of the exiting fluxes across each of the other faces, which also equals  the sum of their foreshortened areas.

Each foreshortened area (on any face $F$) is $ n\cdot \vec A_F$  where $\vec A_F$ is the area-normal vector associated to that face; i.e. the vector whose magnitude is an area and whose direction points outward perpendicularly from that face.

The three coordinate faces have known area-normal vectors: $A_x \vec i, A_y\vec j, A_z\vec k$. (As you observed in your post, these three areas can each be computed using the 2x2 determinant formula.)


Thus (1) can be written as  $$(4) \qquad \vec n \cdot \vec A_S=\vec n\cdot<A_x,A_y, A_z>$$

Since this identity is true for any choice of $\vec n$, we can now pick $\vec n$ in order to maximize the flux through $S$. It is geometrically clear that we want $\vec n$ to be the unit normal to the face $S$ to maximize the flux through $S$ (to minimize the effect of foreshortening).

On the other hand, the maximum value of the dot product $\vec n\cdot<A_x,A_y, A_z>$ occurs when $\vec n $ is parallel to $<A_x,A_y, A_z>$ ( a basic fact about dot products).
Thus the optimal chooice of $\vec n$, namely the unit normal vector to $S$, has the same direction as the vector whose components are computed by 2x2 determinants: the vector $<A_x,A_y, A_z>$.

Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed!

That's a brilliant answer, well done!

It is explained exactly in this letter from Hamilton to Graves. He starts with the notion that there should be an axis $j$ perpendicular to the real axis and the imaginary axis of the complex numbers.
He then considers the product of two triplets $$(a_1+b_1i+c_1j)(a_2+b_2i+c_2j)$$ and is bothered by the $ij$ term. He ultimately develops the quaternion product which includes both the dot product and the cross product. The fact that $i$, $j$ and $k$ are perpendicular is required from the outset.
The algebraic skills of William Hamilton and the language of the day make it a challenging letter to read but, in the context of the resulting quaternions, the products of pairs of what we would call basis vectors are considered to be perpendicular to the pairs.

In case the above link labeled "letter" should ever be broken, the title of the letter and the source is "Copy of a Letter from Sir William R. Hamilton to John T. Graves, esq" and was published in Philosophical Magazine, 3rd series, 25 (1844), pp. 489-95.
