# Is it possible to square vector like this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, vectors, inner-products, 3d

I'm wondering if squaring using a dot product is correct.
For example, let $a,b,c$ be vectors
if $(a+b) = c$
then does squaring it mean that
$(a+b) \cdot (a+b) = c \cdot c$
i.e does $(a \cdot a+2a \cdot b+b \cdot b) = c \cdot c$

Comment: Yes, but $a\times a=0$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388045/intuition-for-cross-product-of-vector-with-itself-and-vector-with-zero-vector). So $a\times b+b\times a=0$, too. And $(a+b)\times (a+b)=0$.

Comment: The OP is asking about the dot product, not the cross product.

Comment: You are correct in stating that $a \times a = 0$. However, $a \cdot a = \left| a \right| ^2$

Comment: Terminologically, we call it a "product" because it is bilinear like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, examine it in Cartesian coordinate form.

Because $a + b = c$, we have
$$a_i + b_i = c_i \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where subscript $i$ indicates the coordinate component.  For 2D, we have $i = 1, 2$ for $x$ and $y$ axes; for 3D, $i = 1, 2, 3$ for $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes; and so on.

For $(a + b) \cdot (a + b) = c \cdot c$ we have
$$\sum_i (a_i + b_i)^2 = \sum_i c_i^2 \tag{2}\label{2}$$

If we substitute $\eqref{1}$ into $\eqref{2}$, we see that it is obviously true: both sides become the same expression.